# Python decoding from iso-8859-5

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, decode

When I parse my email messages via python email.parser.Parser, I had a lot of strings like this:

```
=?ISO-8859-5?Q?=C0=D5=D5=E1=E2=E0_=BF=DB=D0=E2=D5=D6=D5=D9_?=
```

How can i decode this to utf-8 using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input is quoted-printable encoded text.  You can use the module `quopri` to handle that:

```
import quopri

incode = '=?ISO-8859-5?Q?=C0=D5=D5=E1=E2=E0_=BF=DB=D0=E2=D5=D6=D5=D9_?='
inencoding = incode[2:12]  # 'ISO-8859-5'
intext = incode[15:-2]
result = quopri.decodestring(intext).encode(inencoding)
```

Result will then be

```
Реестр_Платежей
```

Around the quoted-printable encoding you additionally have an email-header formating, specifying the character encoding the string should be interpreted in after applying the quoted-printable decoding.  The example code above substrings the portions "manually", but you also can solve all that in one step:

```
import email

[ (text, encoding) ] = email.header.decode_header(incode)
result = text.decode(encoding)
```

`result` now will again be the string given above.

Comment: I found a way to do the splitting of encoding name and text by using the `email` module.  I changed my answer accordingly.